# cron job make directory visable

Tags: php, cron, file-permissions, jobs

I have a directory on the server - var/www/html/content - and I would to give everything inside this directory, recursively, 755 permissions (or maybe 757, that's not really important at this point) at exactly 9:30am every day.

I thought the best way to do this would be to create a .php file that contains something like;

```
$ chmod -R 757 var/www/html/content/
```

I'm guessing I'd need an su command in there to switch to root as well???

Then all I would need to do is set up a cron job through the command line. Something like;

```
30 09 * * * /var/www/html/run-job.php
```

Is this about right? Is there a better way to do this kind of task? I've never done anything like this before...

**EDIT**

I've been asked to add some more context...

Basically, the "content" directory essentially holds a library of PDF, Excel and HTML files. Different PDFs on different topics going out routinely, about once a week, but they have to be released at 9:30am on a specific day.

If i set this cron job up correctly then I can upload the files the day before (sometime in the afternoon) and I don't have to worry about being in at 9:30 the next day to do it manually.

All I would need to do is move the files over, change the permissions to 000 (or something so the public or apache can't view it) and then at 9:30 on the day my script can make all of it visible for me whilst I'm at home sleeping.

Make sense?

Comment: Could you add a little bit more context? Maybe there is another solution entirely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run commands directly from cron, so you can achieve it, by putting to cron:

```
30 09 * * * /bin/chmod -R 757 /var/www/html/content/
```

You can edit cron jobs for current user, by entering:

```
crontab -e
```

You can see list of cron jobs for current user, by entering:

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: i get an error; bash: 30: command not found. Do i need a prefix??

Comment: Try /bin/chmod instead of chmod

Comment: Same error.. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? At the moment I go on to the command line. Log in as me. Then su to root. Enter the password.. then I'm typing in the statement above. No step in between?

Comment: Oh... that's a crontab line, so after login as root type:
crontab -e, add this line at the end, save and exit.

Comment: when I type crontab -e and hit enter it returns "no crontab for root - using an empty one" - this is followed by a load of ~ characters on new lines with `"/tmp/crontb.ICL4Nd", OL, OC` at the end - and it won't physically let me type anything in after that. so I have to close the command line and start again. And when I go back and type crontab -l - it returns `no crontab for route` still

Comment: I assume crontab -e opens in vim. So you can enter `i`, then paste this command, then hit esc, then type `:wq` and hit enter. Or you can run command  `export EDITOR="pico"` and `export VISUAL="pico"` and after that you can try to use crontab -e

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35353/discussion-between-nazin-and-mike-lovely)

Comment: Ok - I got there in the end. I'd never heard of vim before today. Really not much experience with command line programming. The "load of ~ characters" I was referring to in the earlier comment was indeed the vim. I typed "i" as instructed and was then able to type out the crontab command in your answer. I then double checked it had been saved through crontab -l, and it has. Thanks.